# I want to add a circular profile image inside my constraintlayout which is inside the cardview which is again inside cnstrntlyout like whtsappp

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout, android-imageview

[Like this (watsapp SS)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K7Y2z.jpg)

I'm stuck with it I can not find how to round profile pics like this and than I don't know how to constraint my my 3 text views basically I'm trying to create something like this

[Screenshot of what I'm trying to say](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YcNy.jpg)

The problem in the above screenshot (which is of a tutorial on youtube) he used vector asset as an profile but I want to use jgp files and than round it and constraint my 3 textviews accordingly like I said.
I would love some help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try ShapeableImageView in your android project.
To use above view in android, you need to add dependency material design 1.2.0 or higher.

> implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0'

In your style.xml add,

```
<style name="ShapeAppearanceOverlay.App.CornerSize50Percent" parent="">
        <item name="cornerSize">50%</item>
    </style>
```

In your layout file , add this view

```
<com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        app:strokeColor="@android:color/darker_gray"  
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/ShapeAppearanceOverlay.App.CornerSize50Percent"
        />
```

Result

[image]

Comment: Thats the easiest way thanks .

Comment: Marked it . Can i ask as a beginner is it a good approach to use such dependencies just like i used your given dependency for circular profile ?

Comment: Yeah it is not a third party library.. This library is backed by google..

Comment: should i be careful about a third party dependency ? and plz tell me are dependencies same as libraries im confused i thought we can only use libraries by importing in topmost of our java class

Comment: If your application uses a library than your application has a dependency on that library. An application can have multiple dependencies like configuration , database etc.. Libraries are one type of dependency.

Answer (score 0):

You can try these libraries

[CircleImageView](https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView)
or
[RoundedImageView](https://github.com/vinc3m1/RoundedImageView)

According to your requirements

Answer (score 0):

You can either make the shapes yourself in the drawable folder which is a lot of work or use third party libraries like hdodenhof/CircleImageView.

I recommend using the third party library so that you can access it in your xml layouts like any other components

Comment: Thanks for your response, can i ask one more thing? I have a String array in my string.xml file and i want to access it in my other xml files textViews but i can not see my string array name in the pop out when i reference @string , only the app name string is showing.

Comment: String array compose many strings which the textview doesn't have a format of showing them. Textview only show a single string not multiple in terms of arrays. If you want to show your data from your string array, you will have to do more munipulation in the main activity